# Does Solomon's digging have any effect on gameplay?

Tags: ios, solomons-boneyard

I have occasionally caught Solomon in the process of digging up more graves in the midst of the battle.  Getting close to him while he's digging causes him to jump out and run away.

Does interrupting his grave-robbing have any gameplay effect, such as altering the number of enemies in the next wave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the official forums, it seems that the only benefit to interrupting Solomon's digging is the OpenFeint achievement.

Comment: Is there a specific source you could link?

Comment: Couldn't find a good linkable example, so I just asked: http://raptisoft.com/forum/index.php?topic=316